# Converting code from php to java. I converted most of the code, But still i am getting some erros

Tags: java, php, oop

PHP code.

```
   function convetDecimalTo brinary($a){
     $binary =array();
     $temp=array();
     for($i=0;$i<8;i++){
      $binary[]=($a%2);
      $a=intval($a/2);
    }
    for($i=7;$i>=0;$i--)
      $temp[]=$binary[$i];
      $binary=$temp;
     return $binary;
 <?php
     $no=0;
    for($i=255;i>=0;$i--){
    $binary=convertdecimaltobrinary($i);
   echo"<tr>";
    $no++;
    echo "<td>{$no}</td>";
    foreach($binry as $biner){
    echo {$biner};
    }
 }
?>
```

I converted some of the code. Could anyone help me with this? As I ran the code I got the below error

> Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList

```
public class Prob1 {
public static  void convertdecimaltobrinary(a){
     ArrayList<Object> brinary;
     ArrayList<Object> temp;
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
    brinary=a%2;
    a=a/2;
    }
    for (int i=7;i>=0;i--){
    temp=brinary[i];
    brinary=temp;
    //return brinary;   
    for (int i=255 ;i>=0;i--) {
        binary=convertdecimaltobrinary(i);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the type of `a`

Comment: when I declare the type it throws an error across the code.

Comment: How are you declaring the type? What is the error message?

Comment: when i declare the type Int 1.The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Object>

Comment: because you're trying to set the value of `a%2` in a list. Considering your php code, I think it should probably be `brinary.add(a%2)`; also declare the type of a.